# express.js function doesnt execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ubuntu-16.04

I declared this function:

```
function current_date_time() {
  var current_date_time = Date.now();

  var current_date_time_2 = current_date_time + 7200000;

  return current_date_time_2;
}
```

I'm using this inside my post route:

```
router.post('/admin/add-product', requireAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
  var product_name = req.body.name;
  var product_price = req.body.price;
  var product_dimensions = req.body.dimensions;
  var product_small_desc = req.body.small_desc;
  var product_desc = req.body.desc;
  var product_date = current_date_time(); // <---- here

  var product_set = {
    product_name,
    product_desc,
    product_small_desc,
    product_dimensions,
    product_price,
    product_date
  }

  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) return res.send(server_error)

    connection.query('INSERT INTO product SET ?', product_set, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) return res.send(server_error)

    })
    connection.release();
  })
})
```

I want it to insert Date.now() PLUS 2 hours (7200000) but it's still inserting Date.now() without 2 hours.
I manually ran the function and it's executing the way I want it to. What's going wrong? Thanks in advance.(PS: I use ubuntu 16.04, therefore I need to workaround the time to get the correct unix value)

Comment: `[...]I use ubuntu 16.04, therefore I need to workaround the time to get the correct unix value[...]` why do you think that this is the case? It looks like you try to solve a time zone issue the wrong way.

Comment: I would suggest using a library to manage dates and datetimes, like momentjs https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I need to insert the data as unix, it's a requirements and I haven't found a way to do it via moment.js..

Comment: @t.niese Becuase I tried everything but Date.now() is still returning the universal time NOT the local one.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleDateString
Might help

Comment: @CedricHadjian  `Date.now()` has to always return the universal one (that's how it is defined), and you should always store the universal one in the database. If you need to display the date in an different timezone, then you might need to use `SET time_zone;` for the mysql connection or if it is about the formatting in JS or an other application, then use a library that handles the correct display for you. But without knowing exactly what you do with the time information and where the exact problem is, it is not possible to tell you how a correct setup would look like.

Comment: But using `current_date_time + 7200000` as a _fix_, is very unsafe method to do that. If the time zone settings in the server configs change for some reason (e.g.  on an update) then your whole _fix_  will fail, and you will have a real mess.

Comment: @t.niese I need to fix the Date.now() itself, I'm also using it to check if a token has been inserted between certain hours. I did `SET time_zone;` in mysql.

Comment: The Unixtime returned by `Date.now()` is the time since 1/1/1970 **UTC**, and can it clearly identify the local time. Therefore, no offset must be added to it. Checking if the token is inserted between two times (local time) works without problems, if the Timezones are set everywhere.  Again _fixing_ the `Date.now()` is the wrong way to _solve_ the problem, because it is just a hack to get it work, which can lead to a disaster in future. If it doesn't work, then the problem is somewhere else and not `Date.now()`,  you probably have wrong comparison int a SQL query somewhere.

Comment: @t.niese I fixed it by using moment.js and mysql's default_timestamp. Everything is working fine now, should I delete this post?

Comment: That’s up to you. If you think that you can create a complete and useful answer the you can answer your own question.